# How do I convert a date entered in a Masked Text Box into a usable value for say, strings and integers? How do I calculate 2 dates as strings?

Tags: label, output, date-arithmetic

I'm fairly new to the world of programming, and I am just trying to make a basic program (In visual basic) that displays a name, your age based on your date of birth, a hobby and a dream all in a readable format using Concatenate operators.

My questions boil down to these: "How do I calculate a date that a user gave me to the current date (Not sure how I would input the current date either)", and "How do I convert the date that the user gave me from a string to something that can be displayed" (Since all I have learned so far is how to output text using labels, I want to convert the result to that)?

Comment: where is your effort?

Comment: Please clarify.

Comment: Have you googled about it?

Comment: I have, but the results I have found have not aided me thus far.